# Is multiwindow feature supported in android except samsung

Tags: android, samsung-mobile-sdk, multi-window

Is multiwindow feature is supported in android sdk without using samsung devices...? I believe it is only supported in samsung and not in native sdk. Please advice for this.

Comment: There is no native Android SDK for multiwindow. The only SDKs are OEM built or included in custom ROMs.

Comment: Thanks [A.C.R. Developement](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1499541/a-c-r-development)